# How to parse an array from JSON object in NodeJS?

Tags: json, node.js

I have a JSON data something like:

```
'1': 
  { code: '1',
    type: 'car',
  },
 '2': 
  { code: '2',
    type: 'bike'
  },
  ...
```

I dont want to parse 1 and 2 in the parent. Only I need to have

```
  [{code: '1',
    type: 'car',
  }, 
  { code: '2',
    type: 'bike'
  },
  ...]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonArray = [];
for (var i in JsonData) {
  jsonArray.push(jsonData[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like for(var in ...) in NodeJS. Are there?